# Python. Подсветка результатов поиска

Tags: python, linux

Есть скрипт:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

city = ('Moscow','SPb','Moskva')
searchword = 'Mos' # запрос может и меняться:
# searchword = raw_input('Поиск по части слова: ') 
res = []
for words in city:
    if all(ss in words for ss in searchword):
        res.append(words)
for items in res:
    print items
```

Результат:

```
Moscow
Moskva
```

Возможно ли сделать подсветку символов "Mos" в результате, к примеру, зелёным цветом?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Можно воспользоваться модулем [`termcolor`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/termcolor).

```
from termcolor import colored

print(colored('Mos', 'green')+'kow')
```

Можно использовать вместе с `raw_input`:

```
s = raw_input('Input ' + colored('string: ', 'red'))
```

Модуль маленький, компактный (5kb). Можно даже не устанавливать, а просто бросить файл `termcolor.py` в каталог с файлом Python-программы.

Недостаток: плохо работает с консолью в Windows. У меня вообще не заработало. Но в Linux и PyCharm работает нормально.

---

Воторой вариант - [`colorama`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/colorama). Её уже придётся устанавливать (`pip install colorama`), да и работать с ней чуть сложнее:

```
import colorama

colorama.init()

print(colorama.Fore.GREEN + 'Mos' + colorama.Fore.RESET + 'kow')
```

У неё всё наоборот - в консоли Windows и Linux работает, а в PyCharm - нет.

---

**Update**

А вот так можно сохранять строки с цветовым выделением в списках и затем выводить из в консоль. Также решается проблема подсветки найденной части строки.

```
from termcolor import colored

searchword = 'Mos'
cities = ('Moscow','SPb','Moskva')
result = []

for city in cities:
    begin = city.find(searchword)
    if begin >= 0:
        end = begin + len(searchword)
        result.append(city[0:begin] + colored(city[begin:end], 'green') + city[end:])

for r in result:
    print(r)
```

Comment: спасибо, `termcolor` отлично подходит. Но что делать, если поисковый запрос будет через `raw_input`?

Comment: @zombic Работает. Обновил вопрос.

Comment: Не то, нужно, чтобы в результате поиска в словах `Moskow` и `Moskva` буквы `Mos` подсвечивались. Если честно, я не представляю, как это сделать с помощью `termcolor`.

Comment: @zombic Вообще не понял, почему это является проблемой. См. Update в ответе.

Comment: не заметил update. Всё отлично работает, спасибо за помощь!